# Visual Studio 2022 crashing while opening a Windows Form form with many controls in design mode

Tags: windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022, crash-reports

I have `MS Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit) v.17.4.2` crashing while opening a form in design mode in Windows Forms project (.NET Framework 4.x).
This form has many `UserControl`s. The Windows Forms project is a 64-bit one recently converted from 32-bit Visual Studio 2019 project. The application and this problematic form work well when running from within Visual Studio 2022 (Ctrl+F5) or within standalone Windows Forms .NET Framework 4.x application.

The crashing issue should be somehow caused by one of the `UserControl`s but while crashing Visual Studio 2022 doesn't produce any logs - it just crashes silently.

How can I capture/log any info on such an issue to modify my `UserControl`s design/code behind?

I must note I have another Visual Studio 2022 Windows Forms .NET Framework 64-bit project with a (much) more complicated main form and related `UserControl`s design and this form gets opened in design mode without any issues.

Comment: A seemingly silent crash can happen when one of the controls generates a StackOverflowException at design-time.  Debug it by starting VS again and attaching the debugger to the first instance of VS.

Comment: Yes, attaching the debugger to the first instance using this technique "[Set up the project for design-time debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/walkthrough-debugging-custom-windows-forms-controls-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)" helped to localize the issue in one of the `UserControls`: it wasn't `StackOverflowException` - it was an attempt to read non-existing custom settings file. And the (`FileNotFound`) exception wasn't handled (it's handled on run-time only).

Answer (score 0):

hi not sure about VS 2022 but for vs 2019 you have to set the target cpu to x86, edit the form then set it back to x64 to run, not ideal but seems to work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue was caused by an attempt to read non-existing custom settings file in design mode.